# Creation of search using JAVA API from Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, java

Here I am creating a java program which connects to a Marklogic Database and retrieves the documents using the string Keyword. Below is the program created.

```
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClient;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory;
import com.marklogic.client.DatabaseClientFactory.Authentication;
import com.marklogic.client.document.BinaryDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.document.JSONDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.document.TextDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.document.XMLDocumentManager;
import com.marklogic.client.io.Format;
import com.marklogic.client.io.StringHandle;
import com.marklogic.client.query.QueryManager;
import com.marklogic.client.query.StringQueryDefinition;

public class dcb_conn {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8004, "venkatesh", "F1mas", Authentication.DIGEST);
    BinaryDocumentManager binDocMgr = client.newBinaryDocumentManager();
    XMLDocumentManager XMLdocMgr = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
    JSONDocumentManager JSONDocMgr = client.newJSONDocumentManager();
    TextDocumentManager TextDocMgr = client.newTextDocumentManager();
    QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
    StringQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newStringDefinition();
    StringHandle resultsHandle = new StringHandle().withFormat(Format.XML);
    query.setCriteria("Venkatesh");
    queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
  }
}
```

I am not getting any document results (such as ABC.xml) instead I am getting the below mentioned result. Could you please advise what I am missing here?

```
10:24:36.139 [main] DEBUG c.m.client.DatabaseClientFactory - Creating new   database client for server at localhost:8004
10:24:36.155 [main] DEBUG c.m.client.impl.JerseyServices - Connecting to localhost at 8004 as venkatesh
10:24:36.319 [main] DEBUG c.m.client.impl.JerseyServices - Searching for Venkatesh
```

Answer (score 4):

In cases like this, first ensure that you are able to READ the documents in question with the user you are using for searching. I usually do this sanity check with cURL to the document get REST API, for instance

IF you are able to GET the document, then the search fails, this could also be due to language settings.

So, the short suggestion is  -remove as many moving parts as possible and test directly against ML with the user (query console and/or REST, etc)

Comment: Also note that your search has an upper-case letter, which means it will be run case sensitive by default (see [Usage Notes on cts:word-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query). Make sure you data has case-matching text or use a lower-case query.

Comment: Thanks David. I have modified my program as mentioned below and it is displaying the results now.

DatabaseClient client = DatabaseClientFactory.newClient("localhost", 8004, "admin", "admin",Authentication.DIGEST);
  QueryManager queryMgr = client.newQueryManager();
  StringQueryDefinition query = queryMgr.newStringDefinition();
  SearchHandle resultsHandle = new SearchHandle();
  query.setCriteria("Venkatesh");
  // run the search
   queryMgr.search(query, resultsHandle);
  // Format the results
   TutorialUtil.displayResultURIs(resultsHandle);
   client.release();
 }
}

Comment: Also I have a question how  to search document using name of document in case of building GUI with JAVA API. Please advise.

Comment: You should really ask this as a separate question. Others will not benefit from the answers with it embedded in your original one. Be that as it may, you should look at structured query if you want to search specific documents (or a combined query that can hold both your string query and a structured query). You want StructuredQueryBuilder.document. You can find more info here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_70572, and http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_76144.

Comment: Please take Kim's advice and refer to the documents she provided. If this  does not suffice, then ask this as a new question - it keeps Stack Overflow nice and clean. However, It should be noted that your question - if posted as written - will likely be considered too vague, so there would be little for people to guide you on besides the docs already listed in this thread.

Comment: Also, if the original question was answered, please mark one of the responses as the accepted answer. This way people know to focus their assistance on tickets still needing assistance.